# Model the tied end of a nylon/plastic bag

Tags: modeling

I was searching over but can't find the topic similar. I wan't to make a plastic/nylon bag like this, anyone know the method ?
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific, do you mean modelling the bag? If that's the case the best method is to start with a low poly with few extrusions, to make the broad shape, then sculpt with dyntopo for details and wrinkles.

Comment: sorry! I edit the question :D. Thanks for the answer, I never sculpt before. I will try it.

Comment: Please edit your question to talk about what you've tried and what you're having trouble with. Tutorial requests are outside the scope for this site. If this is NOT a tutorial request, please change your question to sound less like a tutorial request.

Answer (score 1):

### Modeling

Go to a new scene and delete the default cube. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>dd a *Cylinder* mesh. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*. Key <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> and then <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to enter *Front Orthographic View*. Key <kbd>Z</kbd> to enter *Wireframe View* and <kbd>B</kbd>ox deselect the top verticies (drag to create the box with the middle-mouse button). Key <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> to scale the bottom vertices. Your mesh should presently look like this:

[image]

Change into *Edge Select Mode*, key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice to deselect everything, and <kbd>B</kbd>ox select all lateral edges (the ones along the side going from top to bottom). At the bottom of the *3D Viewport*, go to *Select > Checker Deselect*. Your mesh should have these edges selected:

[image]

Key <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>. Enter *Face Select Mode*. Select the top and bottom faces (bases) of the mesh. Key <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Faces*. Your mesh should now look like this:

[image]

Reenter *Vertex Select Mode*. Select two vertices opposite each other on the larger side of the mesh. Key <kbd>O</kbd> to turn on *Proportional editing*. Set the *Falloff type* to *Random*. Key <kbd>S</kbd> to Scale and move the mouse's scroll wheel one way or another until the white circle covers the whole mesh. Scale inwards.

[image]

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Object Mode*. Go to the *Object modifiers* tab in the *Properties panel*. Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Set both the *View:* and *Render:* values to 2. In the *3D Viewport's Tools panel*, select Shading: *Smooth*.

### Texturing

Go to the *Materials* tab in the *Properties panel*. *+ New* to add a new material. Select *Add Shader* from the shader drop down menu. In the top slot under the *Add Shader*, select *Translucent BSDF*. In the bottom slot under the *Add Shader*, select *Refraction BSDF*. If you go into the *Node Editor*, you may find something like this:

[image]

Finished .blend file:

[image]